# Error after publishing the App on Azure

Tags: .net, botframework

I am working on Bot framework technology. Everything was working fine(when I was using localhost url in bot emulator) but after I published my bot in azure, then by using the publish URL I am trying to test it in bot framework channel emulator, it always responds with the same message "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue". The log says "POST Request to 'https://************.azurewebsites.net/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error". I get the same reply when I register my bot on https://dev.botframework.com/bots and try to send messages using web chat(I filled the App ID and App Password fields in web.config). Why am I getting that error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you enter your App ID and password into the Emulator connection settings? Once your bot is deployed you need to use the app credentials in the Emulator to connect to your bot.

Comment: Have you enabled application insights to try to get more information?

Comment: @NilsW I did that

Comment: @JasonSowers how to do that and what information do I get from it?

Comment: [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-app-insights-keys) will walk you through enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Please review the [Connect to a bot that is hosted remotely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator#a-idremotehosta-connect-to-a-bot-that-is-hosted-remotely) documentation section.

In summary, you need to:

- Populate the `Microsoft App ID` and `Microsoft App Password` fields with the ones you obtained after registering the bot in the Bot Framework portal
- Ensure that `ngrok` is installed and that the emulator's App Settings specify the path to the `ngrok` executable. `ngrok` enables the emulator to communicate with your remotely-hosted bot.

Comment: Did you fill the AppId and AppPassword values in the web.config too?

Comment: Yes I filled both the fields in Web.config file